# MATLAB Warnings under fmincon

Tags: matlab, suppress-warnings

I'm minimizing a function with the `fmincon` routine.

This function uses the `integral` command several times. However, some of those integrals turns out to be `Inf` or `NaN` and I don't want MATLAB to show a warning when this happens (the function is always finite).

I've tried using the command `warning('off','MATLAB:integral:NonFiniteValue')` but it don't seem to be working when running the optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be you're simply suppressing the wrong message. You could inspect the values of

```
[a,b] = lastwarn
```

inside an output function (`opts = optimset('OutputFcn', @myOutFcn);`) to make 100% sure you're killing the correct warning message.

But I too have encountered this annoying behavior before -- you just can't seem to suppress certain warnings in MATLAB's own functions. For those, you have to resort to ugly and fragile hacks.

You could try

```
warning off
... 
warning on
```

which suppresses *all* warnings for all code contained in the '`...`' section.

You could also use an undocumented feature: temporarily promote the warning to an error:

```
ws = warning('error', 'MATLAB:integral:NonFiniteValue');
...
warning(ws);
```

and wrap it up in a `try....catch`. Chances are you then interrupt `integral` and thus `fmincon` prematurely and will thus have to wrap it up together with some rescue mechanism, but that gets real complicated and real ugly real fast, so that's only to be used as a last  resort...

...so in all, it's easiest to just live with the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative way: click on the uppermost link in inner matlab files that produced that warning, find warning ID & copy it into clipboard.

Then add the following line to your script:

```
warning('off','IDHERE');
```

Replace **IDHERE** with actual ID

See https://tushev.org/articles/blog/17/how-to-suppress-matlab-warnings